# Getting a list of files older that 1 month from now in S3 using the "aws s3" utility

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Once a day I upload backups to S3 using the S3 cli utility `aws s3` and cron. And that's automatic. I want also to be able to remove old backups, ones that are older than 2 weeks or 1 month. What's the best way to do that in the manner, that is, automatically?

As the first step, how can I get a list of files in a bucket that were uploaded over 2 weeks ago via the `aws s3` utility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S3 supports lifecycle policies, so you can have this happen automatically.

Simply create a lifecycle policy that deletes files after 2 weeks. (Note that some storage types - i.e. infrequent access - requires at least 30 days of storage.)

Something like:

```
{
  "Rules": [
    {
      "ID": "Delete after 14 days",
      "Status": "Enabled",
      "Prefix": "",
      "Expiration": {
        "Days": 14
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can't filter based on date using the CLI tool, so you will need to list everything, and do the filtering locally.

Comment: ok, the lifecycles also have many settings. I just need to remove all files older than 2 weeks. I've tried creating a lifecycle but I think I might've created it in a wrong way. How can I create it exactly?

Comment: there's only a pop up/wizard in there. how can I add it as text as you've shown?

Comment: You can use the cli - aws s3api put-bucket-lifecycle: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-lifecycle.html